# Special MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my MongoDB database I have an array (parent_archive_uids) for each record, which contains one or more UIDS. As response for my query I want to get a separate record for each element in this array together with another string (filename.value).

Currently I have the following query:

```
db.files.aggregate( [ 
{ $match: {'filename.value': {'$exists': true, '$not': {'$size': 0}}}},
{ $group: {'_id': '$parent_archive_uids', 'Filename': {'$push': '$filename.value'},}},
] )
```

This gives me the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : [ 
        "4e1dd3d462764bc067cf398e70cfa16a653f39badbc5687fa61b6108bf0f3679_27288071", 
        "bfa178455b9bba5e748897d41f183d3837a51243d0364374c1fa8eea376cab27_27288067"
    ],
    "Filename" : [ 
        "File1"
    ]
}
```

But I would like to have a separate record back for each element in the array, like this:

```
{
    "_id" : [ 
        "4e1dd3d462764bc067cf398e70cfa16a653f39badbc5687fa61b6108bf0f3679_27288071"
    ],
    "Filename" : [ 
        "File1"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : [ 
        "bfa178455b9bba5e748897d41f183d3837a51243d0364374c1fa8eea376cab27_27288067"
    ],
    "Filename" : [ 
        "File1"
    ]
}
```

Is this possible with a MongoDB query? I tried, but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need your `$group` stage. As a rule of thumb `$group` can create arrays while `$unwind` gets rid of them.

You can add an [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage after the `$match`:

```js
{ $unwind: "$parent_archive_uids" }
```

This will create a document for every entry in the `parent_archive_uids` array that contains all the other fields in the document which it came from. If you also want to rename the fields to your desired output names you can do so with [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/index.html) and [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)